# Keyboard Dissmissal in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Keyboard is not dismissing correctly in fl;utter using  `keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,` property inside a singleChildScrollview , when drawer is opened.

need to dismiss the keyboard when drawer is opened

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/assets/90414446/911db935-9a95-466d-9d51-26312ad856e3

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()`

By adding this on drawer open event.

Comment: Added but it still not works, Is there any problem with keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag , it doesn't completely dismiss the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

It handles the scenario where the drawer is already open by unfocusing other widgets to avoid conflicts.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    if (Scaffold.of(context).isDrawerOpen) {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
      child: YourChildWidget(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

if this is not work so use FocusNode like.

```
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    if (Scaffold.of(context).isDrawerOpen) {
           _focusNode.unfocus();
        }
      },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
      child: YourChildWidget(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: This will not work, Since keyboard doesn't knows whether it is focused or not, keyboard will always opens up when drawer is clicked